# Excluding NA's in lm.fit

Tags: r, na, lm

I'm trying to use `.lm.fit` to fit a linear regression (since it's faster than `lm`). I have `NA`'s in `X`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100),batch = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T), phase = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 100, replace = T))
df$batch <- factor(df$batch)
df$phase <- factor(df$phase)
```

Introducing `NA`'s to `df$phase`:

```
df$phase[sample(1:100, 10, replace = F)] <- NA
```

I used `na.action='na.pass'` for creating `X`

```
X <- model.matrix(lm(formula = as.formula("y ~ batch + phase"), data = df), na.action = 'na.pass')
```

But `.lm.fit(y = df$y, x = X)` throws the error:

> Error in .lm.fit(y = df$y, x = X) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

And is not accepting any of the na.action options. For example, with:

```
.lm.fit(y = df$y, x = X, na.action = 'na.exclude')
```

I get:

> Error in .lm.fit(y = df$y, x = X, na.action = "na.exclude") : 
>         unused argument (na.action = "na.exclude")

Is there any way to get `.lm.fit` to skip the `NA` samples and pad the `residuals` with `NA`s for these `NA` samples?

Comment: You could always remove the NAs from df at the start using `df = df[complete.cases(df), ]`. If you wanted to add the NAs back in afterwards, you could always record the indices of the removed values and manually add the NAs after fitting the model.